# Are there any Windows video players that don't stutter when looping?

Tags: video, file-formats, framerate, windows

Title. I have spent the past few hours trying to smoothly loop a short 6-second animation I made in Blender. No matter what I use (VLC, Windows Movies and TV, heck I even tried installing MPlayer), there is always a few-frame delay. GIF format doesn't work for me because the animation is 60fps and not heavily compressed. Any ideas?

P.S. I have read about 30 pages mentioning Linux/Ubuntu players that don't have this stutter, but is there anything for Windows 10?

Comment: If all players show the problem, it is likely that the fault is either with the clip or your hardware. You could share the clip, this may help.

Comment: Sites like imgur and giphy work when looping and VLC is supposed to fix the issue in version 4.0, but imgur/giphy use compression and 4.0 hasn't been released yet. Here's imgur https://imgur.com/a/HQKBJ1E

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, if all players stutter for you then the issue probably isn't the players.

Check the clip to see if the last GOP is 'ragged'. Looping works best when the clip ends cleanly, that is, exactly at the end of a GOP.

ETA:
Many modern codecs are very good at minimizing file size and bandwidth, but one of the things they assume is that the material will be played straight ahead. A clip as short as yours may in fact have only one I-frame (complete frame), at the beginning.

Try encoding in an all-I-frame codec like MJPEG and see if you have better luck.

Comment: It isn't an issue with my animation; a gif format works when I convert it but it loses too much image quality to be viable.